# solve the reminder of $\operatorname{rem}(2^{12},63)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve this question but not able to figure out how to approach it.

Do I have to use CRT in here?

Comment: **Hint**:  $Mod[2^{12}, 63] = Mod[2^{12}, 2^6 - 1] = Mod[(2^6)^2, 2^6 -1] = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for $2^{12}$ mod $63$ then you have:

$$
\begin{split} 2^{12} &\equiv (2^6)^2\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \text{ mod }63 \end{split}
$$

Comment: but how do I figure out the exponent here are 6 & 2? base on 2^x gives the closest number to 63? thx

Comment: The exponents have to multiply to give 12. If you pick 3 and 4 say, then you don't gain anything by working mod $63$ since $2^3=8$ and $2^4=16$ and these don't reduce mod $63$ (so then $(2^3)^4$ is just the same as computing $2^{12}$). The first power you get above 63 is $2^6$ and in this case it's nice that this is $1$ mod $63$ because it makes the next calculation very easy.

Comment: so for another example if i need to find rem(5^18,11). then I take (5^9)^2 therefore gives me 2^2=4 is that correct?

Comment: The method is correct (but not best) however $5^9\equiv 9$ (mod 11), so you would get $(5^9)^2\equiv 9^2\equiv 81 \equiv 4$ (mod 11). Did you mean $(-2)^2=4$? In this case though, you can work with smaller powers to start with since $5^2$ can be reduced mod 11. So $5^2\equiv 25\equiv 3$ mod 11 and then $5^4\equiv (5^2)^2\equiv 3^2\equiv 9\equiv -2$ mod 11. Continuing you get $5^8\equiv (5^4)^2\equiv 4$ mod 11 and $5^{16} \equiv 5$ mod 11. Finally $5^{18}\equiv 5^{16}*5^2\equiv 5*3\equiv 15\equiv 4$ mod 11. Notice no computer is needed in these calculations, but you probably need one for $5^9$

Answer (score 1):

$2^{12} = (2^6)^2 = 64^2 = (63+1)^2 = 63^2 + 2\cdot 63 + 1 = 63a+1$ and so the remainder is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Compute the order of $12$ modulo $7$ and modulo $9$, then deduce its order modulo $63$.